Man sent to prison after his wife is attacked and has to fight inmates
I had seen this movie maybe at least 5 years ago. Released probably somewhere in the early 2000, I think American film?
A husband and his wife moves to another country because of the husbands job. He's coming home from work and finds his wife in the washroom bloody and naked on the ground. The bad guy is still in the house and the husband finds him. They fight but the criminal runs and husband chases him through the busy streets. They end up fighting on a bus leading both of them getting caught by police.
In court the criminal is not convicted and let go (lack of evidence). Saddened and enraged after court, the criminal is walking away ahead of the husband, turns around and smirks at the husband. Husband takes the gun of the officer standing beside him and kills the criminal. He goes to a prison and is forced to fight other inmates to the death. 
I've been looking all over for this movie and can't seem to find it anywhere. Please help!

Sounds like the Van Damme film In Hell from 2003.

Kyle LeBlanc is an American working overseas in Russia. When his wife is attacked, Kyle rushes home. Kovich, the man who has killed his wife, buys the judge and is found not guilty for lack of evidence. Kyle takes the law into his own hands and kills Kovich, and for this he is sentenced to life in prison without parole. [...]
The warden amuses himself by betting on organized fights between his prisoners to fill his pockets. After savagely killing another prisoner in his first fight, Kyle is continuously forced into more because the warden and guards know he is a sure thing, and slowly he begins to lose his sanity.

He fights his wife's attacker in a street car (that looks like a bus). Here's the trailer:




I just assumed the title was a shout-out to any movie-watchers sentenced to viewing a Van Damme film.
